# Hibernate restriction for "None of the subobjects has attribute = x"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, left-join

I am trying to specify a hibernate restriction that basically checks that none of the objects in a to-many relationship of my target entity have a specific attribute value.

More concretely:
I have three entities with the following attributes (among others):

- Appointment

  - date
- Setting

  - interval to send
- SentMessage

  - appointment
  - setting

A `Setting` specifies when a message should be sent for an `Appointment`. A `SentMessage` saves sent messages which know for which `Setting` they were sent and for which `Appointment`.

In Java and Hibernate annotations it looks like this:

```
public class Appointment {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appointment")
    private Set<SentMessage> sentMessages;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private DateTime date;
}

public class SentMessage {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "appointment")
    protected Appointment appointment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "setting")
    protected Setting setting;
}

public class Setting {
    @Column(name = "intervalUnit", columnDefinition = TimeIntervalUnit.columnDefinition)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TimeIntervalUnit intervalUnit;
}
```

Now when I'm trying to calculate the messages that are due for sending by a specific setting, I always have the setting I'm currently calculating messages for and I only want to send messages for appointments

- which are in the future
- I haven't sent a message for this setting yet

Therefore, whenever I send a message for an appointment due to a setting I create a new SentMessage object with the appointment and the setting and save it. However, I can't get the Hibernate Restrictions specification right to only get those appointments that do not have a `SentMessage` for my current setting.

This is what I currently do:

```
Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(Appointment.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("date", new DateTime()));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("date"));

criteria.createCriteria("sentMessages", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN).add(Restrictions.ne("setting", this.getSetting()));
```

the first part specifies the "in the future" part, the last statement is me trying to express
"Match only appointments which do not have a sent message for the current setting"

I think I need an "left outer join" here, because I want to include appointments which have no sent messages. I only want to exclude those which DO have a specific sent message (one for the current setting).

By using a "left outer join" I hope to get a list of appointments such that for all those appointment which do not have any sent messages the attributes of "sent message" will be null which should result in true for `Restrictions.ne("setting", this.getSetting())`, causing the to be included in the result.

However, my result set is always empty, even though I have

- appointments which do not have sent messages
- appointments which DO have a sent message for the given setting (so they should not be included)
- appointments which DO have a sent message, but no setting specified on the sent message (so they SHOULD be included)

I'm basically looking for a "NONE OF" statement in Hibernate and thought this is how I could build it, but apparently it's not. Any ideas what's wrong?
I'm also open for other suggestions of reaching the same goal.